# south django migrate

Tags: django, django-south

I just did:

```
python manage.py schemamigration TestDBapp1 --initial
python manage.py schemamigration TestDBapp1 --auto
```

Successfully.

But if I enter: `python manage.py migrate TestDBapp1`

I get this: `sqlite3.OperationalError: table "TestDBapp1_xyz" already exists`

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect that you already executed `syncdb` which created the tables. South tries to create them again during `migrate` and naturally the database complains.

To avoid this you have to tell South to "[fake](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/convertinganapp.html?highlight=fake)" the initial migration.

```
python manage.py migrate TestDBapp1 --fake
```

As the name indicates this pretends to migrate. Note that this is an *one time step*. South will handle your future `syncdb` and `migrate` without requiring `--fake`.