# Can't Make my app modifiable in the admin section of Django

Tags: django, django-admin

I am a newbie in django.I am using eclipse for development and My OS is widows 7.I have an app named Mystudent.I am using sqlite3 database.My issue is that When I type `python manage.py migrate Mystudent` it shows a Fatal error that following sql query is failed.It says table `table Mystudent__student already exists`.When I deleted and run this command,it still show this error.I have attached the screen shot.My powershell screen shot is [image].My admin page is : [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to "fake" the migrate. If the table already exists, you can tell south to update to the latest migration by forcing it using the fake option. See [south django migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567256/south-django-migrate)

Comment: I have typed the command,but it still not loading my add in admin page

Comment: does the table exist in the database? You can check by running the `SHOW TABLES` query in sql.

Comment: First, run `./manage.py dbshell` in your console. This will give you access to the sql shell. Then you need to select your database for the application. Type in `SHOW DATABASES`and to list all databases and then `USE <name of database>` to select your database from the list. Now simply type in `SHOW TABLES` and check to see if your table is in the list.